# Set HTTPPassword via REST with @Password function

Tags: javascript, rest, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am creating docs via Domino Access Service and I would like to add the HTTPPassword field.

This field normally is translated via the

```
@Password(HTTPPassword)
```

formula. How can I establish something via a HTTP post? Now the field is set as 'normal text'.

```
var newPersonObj = {Form: "Person", HTTPPassword: "lotusnotes"}; 
$.ajax({ 
url: '/tools/fakenames.nsf/api/data/documents', 
type: 'POST', 
data: JSON.stringify(newPersonObj), 
dataType: 'xml', 
accepts: { 
    xml: 'text/xml', 
    text: 'text/plain' 
}, 
contentType: "application/json" 
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
var newPersonLocation = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Location"); 
});
```

Comment: What do you mean establish ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out I can include the &computewithform=true parameter in the URL so field translation is performed and the @password function is executed in the translation formula for the HTTPpassword field

Answer (score 0):

I guess who want to get data submitted by a POST:

```
Set s = New NotesSession
Set doc = s.documentcontext
If doc.REQUEST_CONTENT(0)<>"" Then'it's a POST
```

Where REQUEST_CONTENT will contain all the data posted in url encoded format (var1=val1&var2=val2...)

If I misunderstood, sorry, and I will erase/edit this response

Comment: no I want to submit data. but I found out I can include the &computewithform=true parameter in the URL so field translation is performed and the @password function is executed in the translation formula for the HTTPpassword field